# React-Native-Geolocation-Service not giving appropiate latitude and longitude

Tags: android, react-native, npm, react-hooks, geolocation

The latitude and longitude provided by React-native-geolocation-service is not changing even changing location from Noida to Ghaziabad.

I have create two different Alerts one in getlocation method and another in watchposition method. The current Alert (that is in getLocation method) and changed alert (that is present in watchposition method) I get to know that the latitude and longitude provided by React-native-geolocation-service is not as per accuracy.
Here is the method that are working for geolocation to getCurrentPosition and to watchPosition whenever user changes position.

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
const getOneTimeLocation = () => {
    setLocationStatus("Getting Location ...");
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        setLocationStatus("You are Here");
        Alert.alert("current"," latitude "+ JSON.stringify(position.coords.latitude)+ " Longitude "+ JSON.stringify(position.coords.longitude))
        setCurrentLatitude(JSON.stringify(position.coords.latitude));
        setCurrentLongitude(JSON.stringify(position.coords.longitude));
        // weather(false,position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude)
        console.log(currentLatitude,currentLongitude,"dekhooooo")
        // setCurrentLatitude(currentLatitude);
      },
      (error) => {
        setLocationStatus(error.message);
        Alert.alert(error.message);
      },
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 30000,
        maximumAge: 1000,
      }
    );
  };

``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
  const watchPositionMethod = () => {
    watchID = Geolocation.watchPosition(
      (position) => {
        setLocationStatus("You are Here");
        console.log(position);
        Alert.alert("Changed"," latitude "+ JSON.stringify(position.coords.latitude)+" Longitude "+ JSON.stringify(position.coords.longitude))
        setCurrentLatitude(JSON.stringify(position.coords.latitude));
        setCurrentLongitude(JSON.stringify(position.coords.longitude));
        // Alert.alert()
      },
      (error) => {
        setLocationStatus(error.message);
        Alert.alert(error.message);
      },
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        maximumAge: 1000,
      }
    );
  };
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````